# chart is not working in SSRS report after deployment

Tags: ssrs-2008

I have 2 charts in SSRS report. When i was checking my charts in BIDS, it was working fine. But after deployment, Only one chart was working fine. The another one shows 'No data available' message in chart. please suggest some solutions. Thanks. please refer the attached two figures.

Code for Not working chart Dataset(Please refer):

```
    select distinct (select top 1 MIN from SIVA_ControlLimit  where VALIDATE_DATE in (@yr) and ITEM_CODE in (@ITEM_CODE) and 
TEST_TYPE in (@TEST_TYPE) and ITEM_GROUP in (@ITEM_GROUP) and BATCH_NO in (@BATCH_NO) 
order by BATCH_NO,STANDARDVALUE) 'LSL',(select top 1 MAX from SIVA_ControlLimit 
where VALIDATE_DATE in (@yr) and ITEM_CODE in (@ITEM_CODE) and  TEST_TYPE in (@TEST_TYPE) and ITEM_GROUP in (@ITEM_GROUP) and BATCH_NO in (@BATCH_NO) order by BATCH_NO,STANDARDVALUE) 'USL',sum(ORDER_RESULT) 'ORDER_RESULT',BATCH_NO,ROW_NUMBER() 
        OVER (ORDER BY BATCH_NO,ORDER_RESULT) AS Row from SIVA_ControlLimit where
VALIDATE_DATE in (@yr) and ITEM_CODE in (@ITEM_CODE) and  TEST_TYPE in (@TEST_TYPE) and ITEM_GROUP in (@ITEM_GROUP) and BATCH_NO in (@BATCH_NO) 
group by MIN,MAX,ORDER_RESULT,BATCH_NO
order by BATCH_NO
```

[After Deployment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1BSgr.png)

[In BITS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DVuvH.png)

Comment: Are the BIDS and  the Deployed report using the same database?

Comment: Yes Mr.Nick. But i solved the problem just now. Actually i don't need to create another dataset. I am using 2 different datasets for 2 charts.But one main dataset is enough for both charts. So i solved like that. But anyway if i am using 2 different dataset for 2 charts, One chart is always shown "No data Available" message.